# Using Sinatra for Building Web Proxy, Handling I/O Blocking? (+ Strange Heroku request concurrency issue)

Tags: ruby, concurrency, heroku, sinatra, thin

I want to write something similar to an HTTP web proxy. I am currently exploring using Ruby with Sinatra for this.

One of my main worries with this is that the HTTP request I make to another server might take a while to come back. How do ensure I can continue to serve other requests in the meantime?

I created an extremely contrived example that simulates this sort of blocking.

hello.rb:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

set :server, 'thin'

get '/fast' do
    'Fast Hello World!'
end

get '/slow' do
    sleep 10 
    'Slow Hello World!'
end
```

config.ru:

```
require './hello'
run Sinatra::Application
```

What has me absolutely baffled is this. If I run this locally with "ruby hello.rb", accesing /slow will not interfere with accessing /fast. However, if I deploy to Heroku, then suddenly, requests to /fast will wait for requests to /slow to finish up. I had thought that both locally and on Heroku, this app was running on single-threaded Thin. I cannot understand why I get different behavior.

I am pretty new to all this. Why am I experiencing this inconsistent behavior? What would be a good way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're running a single process locally? The behaviour you describe on heroku is what I would expect - provided your heroku app has only one dyno. In any case, for non-blocking requests you might want to have a look at http://rubyeventmachine.com/ or if you don't care for ruby, http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the command "ruby hello.rb" will shutdown the web server of thin after you run a request,  but the heroku will keep your ruby thread alive on web server, so you could try more time with the HTTP request.

You could do it with this `thin start`(make sure your current directory has the config.ru) if you have installed the server thin, you will see the resulte as the heroku.

Comment: Thanks. Running "thin start" gets me the same behavior as Heroku. Thanks. What I can't understand then is: what is "ruby hello.rb" doing? (It's apparently not the same as "thin start" but I'm afraid I don't understand what it actually is.)

Comment: The different is the "thin start" will boot a web server that keeps the hello.rb script alive in a process till the web server down(Ctrl+C), rather the `ruby hellp.rb` just runs, then shutdown immadiately.